# Amazon Data Transfer OUT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I am a developer at a start up company.

I am now at a point to choose the cloud service.

My server's primary task is to send and recieve jpeg images(about 1mb). We are estimating 100,000 users, 50 requests for images for each user for each month. There fore about 5TB(100K * 50 * 1mb) data transfer OUT is made.

Total cost for data transfer is 1005$(5000GB * 0.201$ --> Japan region price for CloudFront and EC2) each month.

For a start up company, this is a very big investment for a start-up company.

Is there a way to reduce data transfer cost?

Comment: $1005 per month data transfer for 100,000 users at a start up?  I wouldn't suggest that's a big investment.  It's going to cost regardless - I'd be looking more at how the revenue shapes up for those 100,000 users.

Comment: I guessed wrong on the budget for server abroad. In Korea, where our app will be mainly deployed, IaaS companies give free 1TB data transfer for each instance and 0.06~0.1$ for additional 1GB. I was considering AWS for their reputation and good service.

Comment: AWS costing is different.  You need to consider a lot more than just data transfer.  What percentage will come from edge locations around the world?  Also - what percentage of cache hits will you get?  Can you serve the images via S3 rather than EC2?  And this isn't even touching the things you haven't mentioned.  (EC2 usage, scaling sizes, cloudwatch alarms, elastic load balancing, number of GET/PUT requests, EBS)  Realistically - if $1005 feels like too big an investment for that much data and users, then your going to struggle on AWS once you add all that other stuff in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options:

1. You could use [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com/) instead of CloudFront. They provide CDN functionality for free.
2. If you don't use S3 to serve images, but do it from your servers, you could use different provider. For instance Linode has DC in Tokyo, where 4 GB ($80) gives you 8 TB transfer. Another one is vps.net - 1 GB instance ($40) gives you 6 TB of transfer. You can also play a bit with [Cloudorado](http://www.cloudorado.com/) to find something for you.

Comment: Will have to test the performance on those later. Although, it seems nothing can beat AWS performance-wise. I'm probably going for AWS and just reduce the size of my images to keep the cost down.